# R: how to calculate an EWMA correlation

Tags: r, plotly, correlation

I have to calculate an EWMA correlation and create a plot with `plotly()` of the data frame `df.dataCorrelation`, which is defined as:

```
date <- c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", 
          "2018-01-09", "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-14", "2018-01-15", 
          "2018-01-16")
prod1 <- c(43.10, 42.56, 41.77, 41, NA, NA, 40.79, 41.03, 40.98, 41.13, 41.98, NA, NA, 40.81, 41.21)
prod2 <- c(19.442, 19.320, 19.204, 18.918, NA, NA, 19.041, 19.452, 19.516, 19.344, 19.840, NA, NA, 
           19.177, 18.974)
df.dataCorrelation <- data.frame(date, prod1, prod2)
```

[image: data frame EWMA]

How do I create an EWMA correlation plot between `prod1` and `prod2`?

**EDIT:**

I've already tried the `qcc`-package and the `ewma()` function:

```
m.ewmaCorr <- qcc.groups(df.ewmaCorr$prod1, df.ewmaCorr$prod2)
l.ewma <- ewma(m.ewmaCorr, lambda = 0.85)
```

But this produces an empty plot:
[image: empty]

Comment: Visit [this](https://cfrm.shinyapps.io/EWMA/)

Comment: @BappaDas thank you, but I need to do this with RStudio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a plotly alternative is acceptable, this works

EDIT (ugly quickfix)

```
library(qcc)
library(corrplot)

date <- c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", 
          "2018-01-09", "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-14", "2018-01-15", 
          "2018-01-16")
prod1 <- c(43.10, 42.56, 41.77, 41, NA, NA, 40.79, 41.03, 40.98, 41.13, 41.98, NA, NA, 40.81, 41.21)
prod2 <- c(19.442, 19.320, 19.204, 18.918, NA, NA, 19.041, 19.452, 19.516, 19.344, 19.840, NA, NA, 
           19.177, 18.974)
df.dataCorrelation <- data.frame(date, prod1, prod2)
df.dataCorrelation <- na.omit(df.dataCorrelation)

df_prod1_ewma<-ewma(df.dataCorrelation$prod1, lambda = 0.85) # give now ewma plot    
df_prod2_ewma<-ewma(df.dataCorrelation$prod2, lambda = 0.85)

result_df<-cbind.data.frame(df_prod1_ewma$y,df_prod2_ewma$y) 

res<-cor(result_df, use="complete.obs")    

x11()
corrplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: I have no problem with the NA-values, I can delete them from my data frame. My problem is that I don't know how to calculate an EWMA correlation between ```prod1``` and ```prod2``` and then display it with ```plotly()```??

Comment: i see. what is the error message you get doing it your way?

Comment: i updated the answer but with corrplot as i have not yet used plotly. i assume though, that the workflow should be similar

Comment: I have now edited my question above, and please just ignore the NA values because I don't need to replace them with weighted values (I remove all rows where the entries are NA). What I need to do, is to calculate the EWMA correlation between the two products and to plot a correlation scatter plot!

Comment: ok, that actually doesn't change the answer except in the ewma function you use.

Comment: When I use your code above, I get the following error: **Error in plot.window (...): finite 'ylim' values required** Do you know why?

Comment: i updated th answer, problem lies with NA. min/max in a column is always NA if NA are present, this messes with limits

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. But I don't see a difference between this EWMA plot and a normal scatter plot? Where does lambda appear? With or without lambda, the data always remains the same.

Comment: lambda just assigns the amount of days you want to go over. a lambda of 0.85 is equivalent to saying i want the ewma to smooth over a 6.67 (let's round this to 7) day period. your data has, (after discarding NA's) a length of 11. i am not sure what you expect. could you please clarify - i probably just missunderstand something

Comment: I already realize that my data with 11 observations (rows) are not meaningful. But my actual data often has 1000 observations (or more, depends on which time period I choose) and here the values of product 1 and product 2 are the same too.

Comment: ah my oversight, i never used qcc, let alone qcc ewma() so i misinterpreted the results. it is not `df_prod1_ewma$statistics` but `df_prod1_ewma$y`. i fixed the answer